# lxml xpath to return one list item for all descendants of node

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

xml:

```
<div class="nsm-brief-primary-title-group">
        <a class="nsm-brief-action-link" href="/Mobile/Search/Title/1.10.1.511937"><span class="nsm-short-item nsm-e135"><span class="nsm-hit-text">Airplanes</span> take off and land</span></a>
    </div>
```

for example this code:

```
titles = tree.xpath('//div[@class="nsm-brief-primary-title-group"]/descendant::*/text()')
print 'titles: ', titles
```

returns a list:

```
titles:  ['Airplanes', ' take off and land']
```

how can I make any text from descendants of a div with that class name appear as a single item in the array?

```
titles:  ['Airplanes take off and land']
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all descendant text nodes from an element as a single string, you can convert the element to string by using XPath `string()` function :

```
title = tree.xpath('string(//div[@class="nsm-brief-primary-title-group"]/a)')
```

If there can be multiple `a` elements within the `div` and you want to have one string from each, then you'll need to apply `string()` function on individual `a` element :

```
titles = [a.xpath('string()') for a in 
            tree.xpath('//div[@class="nsm-brief-primary-title-group"]/a')]
```